# how can i display a productlist in a listbox based on the category button i click on?

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys, categories

I have a menu with buttons, each button has a category on it. Next to the menu i placed a listbox. This listbox is linked to a `productlist` in the database. I want that whenever I press a `categorybutton`, the products linked to that category (with a categoryID) will display in the listbox.

Im using the following code to display the products in the listbox

```
var productslist = from products in db.products select products;
prodlb.ItemsSource = productslist;
```

Comment: Didn't you try using where to filter the products `from product in db.products  where product.CategoryId = selectedCategoryId select product`

Comment: Doesnt work, product.categoryId gets red underlined

Comment: Don't just copy paste the code. Understand the logic. What property do you have in product object to represent category of it?

Comment: I didnt copy paste, but the where clause doesnt work

Comment: There was a slight error in my code. The updated one is `from product in db.products where product.CategoryId == selectedCategoryId select product`. Try this. If there is an error, share the exact error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Buttonproducts_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var productslist = from products in db.products select products;
        prodlb.ItemsSource = productslist;
    }

private void ButtonCustomers_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Customerslist = from Customers in db.customers select customers;
        prodlb.ItemsSource = Customerslist;
    }
```